# jquery window scroll event not working right with overflow-x hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i was using this code for adding some animation to the nav bar

```
    $(window).on("scroll", function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
        $('.top-menu .navbar').removeClass('remove-nav-move');
        $('.top-menu .navbar').addClass('nav-move');
    } else {
        $('.top-menu .navbar').removeClass('nav-move');
        $('.top-menu .navbar').addClass('remove-nav-move');
    }
});
```

then i added some css

```
html , body  {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.full-width-bar {
    margin: 0 -9999rem;
    /* add back negative margin value */
    padding: 0.25rem 9999rem;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

and the  `overflow-x: hidden;` on the body ruin the window scroll so please any help to fix this or any alternative way to do this and many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i didn't find any solution for this so i remove the `overflow-x` but before that i tried and the best thing i come with is

```
  var up_wind = 0;

$(window).bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll wheel", function (event, delta) {
     console.log(delta);
    if (delta>= 0 && delta != "undefined") {
        if(up_wind != 0){
            up_wind--;
            console.log('Scroll up');
            console.log(up_wind);
        }
    }
    else if(delta != "undefined") {
     if(up_wind >= 0)
         up_wind++;

         console.log('Scroll down');
        console.log(up_wind);
    }

    if(up_wind > 1){
        $('.top-menu .navbar').removeClass('remove-nav-move');
        $('.top-menu .navbar').addClass('nav-move');
    } else {
        $('.top-menu .navbar').removeClass('nav-move');
        $('.top-menu .navbar').addClass('remove-nav-move');
    }
});
```

hope will help.